# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'displot'

Tags: python

I have this error when I am using Seaborn. My Seaborn is at version 0.9.0 now. So i don't know what else I can do to troubleshoot this.

My matplotlib is version 3.0.2. My python is Version 3.7. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x)
```

is your code looks like this!

Comment: oh just realize  there is a typo in the code. thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, please don't forget to accept it, by clicking the tick mark. Doing so will help others who read the question in future

Comment: @HellenLai dont forget to up vote the answer

Comment: Is it `distplot` or `displot`? Seaborne doc says it should be `displot` but I cannot find it on my seaborne module. https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer to this question, but with my problem this was the first website that I found. So I want to document my case for future users that may have the same problem.

I copied one example from https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html
and got this error.

It turned out, that seaborn 0.11 introduced displot, while I used seaborn 0.10.

> New plotting functions
>
> First, three new functions, displot(), histplot() and ecdfplot() have been added (#2157, #2125, #2141).
>
> ...
>
> Deprecations API
>
> Finally, the distplot() function is now formally deprecated. Its
> features have been subsumed by displot() and histplot(). Some effort
> was made to gradually transition distplot() by adding the features in
> displot() and handling backwards compatibility, but this proved to be
> too difficult. The similarity in the names will likely cause some
> confusion during the transition, which is regrettable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two modules should be installed additionally:

- statsmodeles
- fastcluster.

For additional details: https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because you forgot the 't' -> it's 'distplot' not 'displot'

Comment: https://github.com/seaborn/seaborn.github.io/issues/2